# How to find duplicates in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory

I am trying to find duplicate objects in AD (windows 2008 r2) by custom attribute employeeId

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(employeeID -like "*")} 
| Select-Object Enabled, ObjectClass, Name, UserPrincipalName, SamAccountName, employeeID 
| 
    ForEach-Object {  
        $obj1 = $_
        ForEach-Object { 
            if($_.employeeID -eq $obj1.employeeID){

            }
        }
    }
| Export-Csv C:\Users\user\Desktop\mployeeId_is_duplicate.csv
```

thanks

Comment: any hint on what is not working ? an error message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try group-object and select all entities with Count > 2 like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(employeeID -like "*")} -property employeeID |Group
employeeid | ? {$_.Count -ge 2} | select -ExpandProperty group | Select-
Object Enabled, ObjectClass, Name, UserPrincipalName, SamAccountName, 
employeeID | Export-Csv C:\Users\user\Desktop\mployeeId_is_duplicate.csv
```